# How can I format a number input as seconds to min:sec in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet in Google Sheets that contains a column of numbers, intended to be interpreted as seconds. I would like to have a second column that has a running total, formatted as `minutes:seconds`. For example:

| Seconds | Running total |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 0:30 |
| 45 | 1:15 |
| 60 | 2:15 |
| 40 | 2:55 |

The running total is easy enough; I can use `=sum(Ax,Bx-1)`, e.g. `=sum(A3,B2)`, and drag this down the column. However, try as I might, I cannot get this to format correctly. If I highlight the column, select `Format > Number > Custom number format` and input `mm:ss`, I get `00:00` in all columns, as it appears to interpret the number as a date. How can I format this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TIMEVALUE, that converts a string to time. The first 0s are for the hours and minutes, therefore considering A2 as the seconds:

```
=TIMEVALUE("0:00:"&A2)
```

You can do what you said for the running total, or you could use SCAN too:

```
=SCAN(0,A2:A,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="","",a+TIMEVALUE("0:00:"&v))))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I ended up using `=sum(timevalue("0:00:"&Ax),Bx-1)` and dragged it to generate the running total.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=SCAN(,A2:A5,LAMBDA(a,c,a+c/1440))
```